# Android - can I increase the textSize for the NumberPicker widget?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

We got a NumberPicker widget in 3.0, but it seems that the textSize for this widget can't be modified. Am I missing something or is this the case? I'd really like to increase the font size, it's quite small with the default value. But I can't see a textSize property for it.

Comment: FYI, if you use **aheuermann's** solution (as I did) and you also want to implement a listener to the number picker, the onValueChanged method will have to look like this. I thought I would share this, since it took me a bit of time to figure this one out. public void onValueChange(android.widget.NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){ //your awesome methods to perform on value changed }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into the same problem and ended up recreating [NumberPicker](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/NumberPicker.java) locally. There's a more in depth tutorial [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131201181107/http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5).

Comment: Can you please share the link for the tutorial again.. as I too need to increase the font size. Thank you

Comment: It wasn't my tutorial, but it looks like the Wayback Machine still has an archived copy of it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20131201181107/http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5.

Answer (score 94):

I was able to accomplish this by extending the default NumberPicker. Not ideal, but it works.

```
public class NumberPicker extends android.widget.NumberPicker {

   public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
   }

   @Override
   public void addView(View child) {
     super.addView(child);
     updateView(child);
   }

   @Override
   public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
     super.addView(child, index, params);
     updateView(child);
   }

   @Override
   public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
     super.addView(child, params);
     updateView(child);
   }

   private void updateView(View view) {
     if(view instanceof EditText){
       ((EditText) view).setTextSize(25);
       ((EditText) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
     }
   }

 }
```

Then just reference this class in your layout xml.

```
<com.yourpackage.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: do you have tried to use variable for textsize and or for textcolor? please check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804573/custom-numberpicker-with-variable-for-textsize

Comment: Nice, upvoted. A note of caution however I tried experimenting with larger font sizes ~42 and NumberPicker started misbehaving when wrap wheel is set to false.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Just don't get it, why Android developers did not provide a possibilty to easily change NumberPicker styling, apparently, it's quite a common use case.

Comment: In some way Android UI creation is really slow and restricted, UI takes time to develop, common controls are easy to create in some other plateforms are to tough to create in Android.

Comment: But that doesn't work. On 6.0 it changes the selected textview, but the adjacent texts stays the same, and the font changes to default one as soon you move the picker!

Comment: This solution slows down the app for me

Comment: I have added this code with much success.  However, I have not been able to implement a listener to this NumberPicker.  Is there something with this solution that does not allow use of a listener?

Comment: @seeking stillness, see solution to implemeting a listener below.

Comment: How to increase the speed of scroll?

Comment: @JacekKwiecień - Is there any way to customize the text size of the selected picker value when there is user interaction

Answer (score 14):

only set this sytle for your NumberPicker:

```
   <style name="AppTheme.Picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
```

```
<NumberPicker
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        android:id="@+id/yearNumberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>`
change textcolor :
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem, I wanted to increase the text size of the NumberPicker but couldn't find a way to do it as part of the Widget. All the above answers are great, but instead I went with the following solution, which met my needs:

```
<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"/>
```

This essentially magnifies the entire Widget.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me (in API 15 / 4.0.3)

**note:** aheuermann's solution is safe against potential implementation differences in the `NumberPicker`'s layout across different Android versions (that is, the `TextView` may not always be at child position 1).

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)_numberPicker.getChildAt(1);
tv1.TextSize = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Jumping to API 23, the solution presented by aheuermann seems to have problems.  In the source for NumberPicker, the text size is set based on the EditText child at initialization.  If you try to change it later, the EditText field will get big, but all other numbers drawn directly by the widget will still be small.

The solution I'm going with has the disadvantage that it must be instantiated programmatically, instead of via layout, but otherwise, it seems to work as intended.  First, add the following to your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="NumberPickerText">
    <item name="android:textSize">40dp</item>
</style>
```

Then, you can instantiate the NumberPicker with

```
    ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.NumberPickerText);
    NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(cw);
```

assuming that it's being done within an Activity.  If not, replace the "this" with whatever Context you have available.  This code does the equivalent of setting a theme that overrides all TextView sizes within your Activity, but only applies it to the NumberPicker and its children.

Comment: Alternative: instantiate `ContextThemeWrapper` in a custom view's constructor (that extends NumberPicker) and pass that to `super`.

Comment: Good solution, However, 'sp' should be used instead of 'dp' for TextSize.

Comment: Working well with compileSdkVersion 29 and minSdkVersion 26. But as an alternative I'm using scale  `<item name="android:scaleX">1.5</item>
        <item name="android:scaleY">1.5</item>`

Answer (score 0):

We can customize views inside NumberPicker.

It has three views-

2 ImageButttons and 1 EditText.

```
    if(numberPicker.getChildAt(1) instanceOf EditText)
    {
        EditText edt=(EditText)numberPicker.getChildAt(1);
        //do customizations here
    }
```

**Complete layout of NumberPicker from Android Source Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
**
** Copyright 2008, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/increment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/numberpicker_up_btn"
        android:paddingTop="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="22dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/number_picker_increment_button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberpicker_input"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Large.Inverse.NumberPickerInputText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/numberpicker_input" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/decrement"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/numberpicker_down_btn"
        android:paddingTop="22dip"
        android:paddingBottom="22dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/number_picker_decrement_button" />

</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

From API 29 you can use method:

```
number_picker.setTextSize( float textSize );
```