# How to reduce the font size in NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

All, I'm customizing a city picker, which uses three numberPicker inside,like this:
[image]

Its a Chinese province-city-area picker.

The code:

```
String[] areas = get_from_somewhere();
areaPicker.setDisplayedValues(areas);
```

I want to reduce the font size,any advice?

**Solution**: [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958460/android-can-i-increase-the-textsize-for-the-numberpicker-widget/12084420#12084420)

Comment: you might be using custom `WheelView` which extends `View` isn't it?

Comment: @Rustam yes,I want a WheelView in android style. founded a sample on Github https://github.com/ywenblocker/Provinces-Picker-wheel ,but it not fits the Holo Theme. Give me more info,plz

Comment: better use this https://github.com/mstorsjo/vlc-android/tree/master/java-libs/WheelView/src/kankan/wheel/widget

Comment: in that there is `AbstractWheelTextAdapter` in `adapter` where you can change the textsize.

Comment: @Rustam Thankyou, its style not fit the android Holo theme, I'm not prefer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend the default `NumberPicker` in your Custom class `CustomNumberPicker` for this:

```
public class CustomNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        if(child instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) child).setTextSize(25);
        }
    }
}
```

Now replace your current `NumberPicker` in xml with `CustomNumberPicker`:

```
<com.pkg.name.CustomNumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thank your answer, I set a breakpoint on ((EditText) view).setTextSize(25); But nothing happened

Comment: Did you use CustomNumberPicker instead of NumberPicker in your xml or activity?

Comment: Yes, I use " provincePicker = new SmallSizeNumberPicker(context, null); " in my constructor, the break point never invokes. I seach the keyword 'addView(' in the source of NumberPicker.java , and get nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63466/discussion-between-ninja-and-mysticmagic).

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

Although technically not changing the font size, the size of the text can be changed by changing the scale of the entire NumberPicker View.

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX=".7"
    android:scaleY=".7"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on **John Starbird** answer.

You add style.

```
<style name="NumberPickerText">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>
```

Add style to your Number Picker in XML.

```
android:theme="@style/NumberPickerText"
```