# Custom NumberPicker with variable for textSize

Tags: android

i was trying to create my own numberPicker as i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958460/android-can-i-increase-the-textsize-for-the-numberpicker-widget/12084420#12084420) , but i can't use a variable to set the textSize.

Can anyone guess why isn't that working?

```
public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    float myTextSize = 35.0f;

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).setTextSize(myTextSize);
            ((EditText) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public void setTextSize(int _textSize) {
        myTextSize = _textSize;
    }
}
```

if I replace this line

```
((EditText) view).setTextSize(myTextSize);
```

with this

```
((EditText) view).setTextSize(35);
```

works, but then I can't change the textSize;

**UPDATE** 
after some more tests, i found out that `addViews` are called after the `setTextSize`, but still when the `updateView` runs the value of `myTextSize` is zero.

Comment: Try to use `setTextSize (int unit, float size)` like `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, myTextSize)`

Comment: TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP

Comment: I still can't understand why the problem you described is happening. Technically there is no difference between `.setTextSize(35)` and `.setTextSize(myTextSize)`